# SAS output statement

Tags: sas

I am trying to change the output of my raw data file. In the raw data, the data are in the following format:

```
Name    Test1   Test2   Test3   Test4
xyz     45      78      88      100
avb     -1      89      76      29
```

But I want to change the data structure to the following format:

```
Name    Score
xyz     45
xyz     78  
xyz     88
xyz     100
xyz     89 (skip -1 because it's less than 0)
```

I am trying to use array and output statement but having trouble. Here is my code:

```
Data Stats; 
  set Record; 
  Array Test(*) Test1 - Test 6; 
  do i = 1 to 6; 
    if Test(i) gt -1 then output; 
  end;
run;
```

Comment: Please provide the code you've tried so we can give useful feedback.

Comment: The code i use is

Data Stats; 
set Record;
Array Test(*) Test1 - Test 6;
do i = 1 to 6;
if Test(i) gt -1 then output;
end;

Thank You

Comment: Please edit that into the question in the future.

Answer (score 5):

What you're missing is moving the value into a single column.  Right now you're getting the right number of rows, but you're not getting the single column.

```
Data Stats; 
  set Record; 
  Array Test(*) Test1 - Test 6; 
  do i = 1 to 6; 
    if Test(i) gt -1 then do;
      score=test(i);  *save value onto Score variable;
      output; 
    end;
  end;
  keep score name;  *only keep the two variables you want;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use proc transpose or Array statement with do loop to solve your problem.

```
data record;
infile datalines missover;
input Name  $ Test1   Test2   Test3   Test4;
datalines;
xyz     45      78      88      100
avb     -1      89      76      29
;;;;
run;

/* Solution #1 : Using PROC TRANSPOSE */
proc transpose data=record out=solution_1(rename=(col1=score) where=(score>0) drop=_name_);
by notsorted name;
var test1--test4;
run;
proc print data=solution_1;run;


/* Solution # 2 : Using Array and do loop */
data solution_2;
set record;
array temp(*) test1-test4;

do i=1 to dim(temp);
score=temp[i];
if score >0 then output;
end;
keep name score;
run;
proc print data=solution_2;run;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem with the very easy method.

```
    data original;

    input Name $ Test1-Test4;

    cards;

    xyz 45 78 88 100

    avb -1 89 76 29
    ;

    run;



    ***now you need to sort your data by Name *************;

    proc sort data=original;
    by Name;
    run;

********************************************************;

    data u_want;

    set original;

    array Test[4];

    do i=1 to dim(Test);

    if Test[i] >= 0 then Score=Test[i]; output;

    end;

    Drop i Test1-Test4;

    run;

    **********************************************************;

    proc print data=u_want;

    run;

Thanks!
```